# Alien plant from another planet moves around a spaceship during the night and finds a sleeping human body to take root in

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, space

A man takes an alien plant from another planet into his spaceship. But what this man doesn't know is that the plant has its own mind, and it moves around during the night looking for somewhere warm. And finally it finds a soft sleeping human body to settle its root in.

Please specify the name and author of the book; also the plot that contains my question, if you know the story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, was this a short story or a novel?

Comment: When I was a primary school student(around 2008). I don't know when it is published, but I think it's old. I am not sure. It's a passage from the original reading. So it could be both.